# Как сделать предложение покупки дополнительного товара в корзине, со скидкой (WooCommerce)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, интернет-магазин

**Задача следующая:** когда посетитель сайта положил в корзину товар из определённых категорий, ему должно выводиться предложение купить другой товар со скидкой. Товар который предлагается купить со скидкой, так же должен быть со скидкой на самом сайте а не только в корзине. Так же, товар который предлагается со скидкой, должен быть со скидкой именно для этого посетителя сайта и именно в тот период пока у него в корзине находятся товары из определённой категории.

**Варианты решения о которых я думал:** Как предложить товар, понятно, это в WooCommerce реализовано по умолчанию. Но как сделать на него скидку, если этот товар изначально продаётся без скидки и показывается всем кто заходит на сайт? То есть, если я установлю скидку на товар при выполнении нужных условий, то этот товар будет показан со скидкой всем, кто заходит на сайт. Если создать копию товара и сделать его со скидкой, но не публиковать например, опять же, не вижу смысла, так как если товар опубликован, он показывается всем. Если товар опубликовать и как-то по кукам скрывать или показывать его с помощью CSS. Ну это уже наверное извращенство. Как можно реализовать такую задачу? Она будет не для одного товара а для разных. Я подозреваю, что нужно будет писать какое-то мини дополнение, для плагина woocommerce, но как это сделать, я не знаю. Возможно есть другие способы? То что сейчас есть, изображено на скриншоте, для наглядности. Буду очень благодарен получить ответ на свой вопрос.

***Сейчас вот так:***

[image: Сейчас вот так]

***Но, при том что все условия соблюдены, должно получиться вот так:***

[image: Должно получиться так]

Comment: Кто-нибудь ещё может помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения именно такой задачи и  многих похожих предназначена [система купонов](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/woocommerce-how-to-manage-coupons.html) WooCommerce.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я обновил информацию в вопросе. Возможно я не правильно понял или не разобрался, но судя по всему, при использовании купонов скидка применяется к товарам в корзине. А мне необходимо сделать скидку на товар который будет предложен в корзине. P.S.: Кому интересно, есть хороший плагин который расширяет функционал системы купонов, называется: WooCommerce Extended Coupon Features.

Comment: Мы так можем тренироваться вечно. Вы задали вопрос - я дал на него ответ. Вы расширили вопрос, так что ответ стал неправильным.

Comment: Я лишь добавил пояснения в виде изображений, к своему вопросу. В остальном, вопрос вообще не изменился как и его суть. Надеялся что дополнительные изображения внесут большую ясность, а не раздражение. В следующий раз я сразу уточню что обновил в вопросе.

Comment: Вот эти изменения принципиально меняют суть вопроса http://take.ms/8ORBB

Comment: Я перечитал свои изменения, действительно, наверное суть меняется. Признаю, был не прав. Хотел описать вопрос более детально, но вышло только запутаннее.